# Correct place to ask SRSS questions

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

Is Stack Overflow the correct place to ask questions about expressions in SRSS?  I couldn't decide if I should post my question here or https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There's 100 or so questions on DBA and almost 11k on SO... I know which one is pick ;-(

Comment: @Ben: Those stats probably aren't per-capita.  Just sayin'.

Comment: What is SRSS? Do you mean SSRS - SQL Server Reporting Services? or SRSS - Sun Ray Server Software?

Comment: SQL Server Reporting Services, my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question needs to be about

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and should be
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

If your SRSS question meets these criteria, then it is on-topic for Stack Overflow.